# MYSQL - Inserting concatenated string

Tags: mysql, database, string, procedure

Table `Items`

[image]

Table `Sale`

[image]

And finally: Table `SaleItems`

[image]

Procedure `PLAYER_CREATE_SALE`:

IN paramters:

- in_player_id int
- in_total int
- in_items_ids nvarchar(500)
- in_items_quantity nvarchar(500)

Basically, the "user" see the list of the Items above, select any item, change the amount and buy. This should works like a "cart".

So, for example: User select bomb(id: 1, quantity: 10) and gear(id: 3, quantity: 2)

The parameters of my procedure would look like this:

`in_player_id: 750`

`in_total: 390`

`in_items_ids: "1,3"`

`in_items_quantity: "10,2"`

This is how works the procedure actually:

```
    INSERT INTO Sale(`player_id`, `total_coins_price`)
    VALUES(in_player_id, in_total);

    SET @sale_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    SET @squery = CONCAT("INSERT INTO SaleItems(`sale_id`, `item_id`, `quantity`) 
SELECT ", @sale_id, ", id, 9999 FROM Items WHERE id IN (", in_items_ids, ")");

    PREPARE stmt FROM @squery;

    EXECUTE stmt;
```

With the code above the result final will be:

[image]

But the quantity is wrong. I don't know how insert the quantity too. Here is how should be:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, can you try to clean up the question it is very hard to follow what you are trying to accomplish. For instance, where does VAR_1 and VAR_2 come from or what are they supposed to reference?

Comment: I guess var_1 is the first 2 ids from otiemsbase and var_2 is manually input by the user?

Comment: SQL doesn't do arrays - to get the elements in var_2 you need to split the string and probably put them into table so that you can change your select to be table based.

Comment: var_1 and var_2 are manually input by the user. Sorry, Im going to try to clean up the question

Comment: Hello, I updated and fixed my question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS P;
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `P`(
    IN `instring` varchar(255)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
begin
declare   tempstring varchar(100);
declare   outstring  varchar(100);
DECLARE   VAR_1 VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE      VAR_2 VARCHAR(100);
declare  checkit int;
DECLARE  LIMITOFFSET INT;

set checkit = 0;
SET VAR_2 = instring;
set tempstring = ltrim(rtrim(VAR_2));
SET LIMITOFFSET = 0;

looper: while   tempstring is not null and instr(tempstring,',') > 0 do
        set outstring = substr(tempstring,1,instr(tempstring, ','));
        set tempstring = ltrim(rtrim(replace(tempstring,outstring,'')));
        set outstring = replace(outstring,',','');
        set checkit = checkit + 1;
        insert into oitems
        select  CHECKIT,10,ID, outstring
         from  OItemsbase 
         order by id
         LIMIT LIMITOFFSET,1
         ;
         SET LIMITOFFSET = LIMITOFFSET + 1;

end while; 
    set outstring = tempstring; 
    set tempstring = ltrim(rtrim(replace(tempstring,outstring,'')));
    set outstring = replace(outstring,',','');
    set checkit = checkit + 1;
    insert into oitems
        select  CHECKIT,10,ID, outstring
         from  OItemsbase 
         order by id
         LIMIT LIMITOFFSET,1
         ;

end //

DELIMITER ;

MariaDB [sandbox]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS OItemsbase;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> CREATE TABLE OItemsbase ( id INT, alpha_id INT, created_at VARCHAR(5));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO OItemsbase VALUES
    -> (2, 100, 'today'),
    -> (6, 101, 'today'),
    -> (10, 101,'today');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists oitemss;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table oitems(id int, example_id int, item_base_id int, quantity int);
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'oitems' already exists
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> truncate table oitems;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> CALL P('20,30');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM Oitems;
+------+------------+--------------+----------+
| id   | example_id | item_base_id | quantity |
+------+------------+--------------+----------+
|    1 |         10 |            2 |       20 |
|    2 |         10 |            6 |       30 |
+------+------------+--------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer. That didnt work for me. Can you check my updated question?

Answer (score 0):

I just added

```
SET @squery = CONCAT("INSERT INTO SaleItems(`sale_id`, `item_id`, `quantity`) 
SELECT ", @sale_id, ", id, 9999 FROM Items WHERE id IN (", in_items_ids, ")");
```

And is working inserting the ids but the quantity is missing.